# MySQL or PHP to calculate percentage of total records?

Tags: php, mysql

Good morning, I have mysql queries where I would like to calculate percentage of total records returned by query as such;

```
Select
  tblcontacts.ContactFullName As Advisor,
  Count(tblcases.CaseID) As Cases
From
  tblcases Inner Join
  tblcontacts On tblcontacts.ContactID =
    tblcases.ContactAssignedTo
Group By
  tblcontacts.ContactFullName with rollup
```

This outputs data Adv 1    100 | Adv 2    300 | Adv 3    600 | 
Total    1000. Would I be able add another column after cases to calculate Cases/Total*100, Adv 1 output writes as 10% for example. From my research I am unsure if its better to do this in php or mysql?

Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code should do the trick:

```
select
    a.advisor,
    a.cases,
    round((a.cases/b.totalCases)*100,2) as PercentCases
from
(
    Select
      tblcontacts.ContactFullName As Advisor,
      Count(tblcases.CaseID) As Cases
    From
      tblcases Inner Join
      tblcontacts On tblcontacts.ContactID =
        tblcases.ContactAssignedTo
    Group By
      tblcontacts.ContactFullName with rollup
) a,
(
    Select
      Count(tblcases.CaseID) As Cases
    From
      tblcases Inner Join
      tblcontacts On tblcontacts.ContactID =
        tblcases.ContactAssignedTo
) b
```

If the tblCases table has no records other than what is being returned in the first query, you can simply the b statement to this:

```
(
    Select
      Count(tblcases.CaseID) As Cases
    From
      tblcases 
) b
```

The PHP Version based on the code that you gave would be like this:

```
<?php
mysql_select_db($database_ghl_portal, $ghl_portal); 
$query_Recordset1 = "
    SELECT 
        tblcontacts.ContactFullName, 
        Count(tblcases.CaseID) As Cases 
    FROM 
        tblcases 
            Inner Join 
            tblcontacts 
            On tblcontacts.ContactID = tblcases.ContactAssignedTo 
    GROUP BY 
        tblcontacts.ContactFullName with rollup";
$totalValue=0;
$i=0;
$Recordset1 = mysql_query($query_Recordset1, $ghl_portal) or die(mysql_error()); 
$row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1); 
while ($row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1))
{
    $totalValue+=$row_Recordset1["Cases"];
    // Do all your other stuff to put the result into an array here such as
    $yourArray[$i][0]=$row_Recordset1["Advisor"];
    $yourArray[$i][1]=$row_Recordset1["Cases"];
    $i++;
}
$totalRows_Recordset1 = mysql_num_rows($Recordset1); 


// And your output code would look like:
for ($j=0; $j<$totalRows_Recordset1; $j++)
{
    echo "Advisor: ".$yourArray[$j][0]."<br>";
    echo "Count: ".$yourArray[$j][1]."<br>";
    echo "Percentage: ".(round(($yourArray[$j][1]/$totalValue),2)*100)."<br><br>";
}
?>
```

Having said that, you should be using the [php PDO object](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) for your queries.

As for helping, it is nice to be able to give back to this community just a fraction of the things I have looked up on here and gotten useful answers to.

Comment: Many thanks for the lightning quick reply much appreciated, that does exactly what I needed, do you know if achieving that result is also possible in php? I only ask as some of my queries going forward already have multiple selects & are quite complex [to me anyway!]. Thanks again great effort

Comment: You can do it in PHP by adding each the total per advisor to a variable in your script (at the same time as you are populating your array for example) then in the display add a percentage column by doing something like $array[advisorTotal]/$overallTotal.

Comment: That's very kind of you, sorry aboyut the format it wont accept my code? 
    mysql_select_db($database_ghl_portal, $ghl_portal);
    $query_Recordset1 = "SELECT tblcontacts.ContactFullName,     Count(tblcases.CaseID) As Cases FROM tblcases Inner Join   tblcontacts On tblcontacts.ContactID =     tblcases.ContactAssignedTo GROUP BY tblcontacts.ContactFullName with   rollup";
$Recordset1 = mysql_query($query_Recordset1, $ghl_portal) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1);
$totalRows_Recordset1 = mysql_num_rows($Recordset1);
?>

Comment: That's superb, as usual I seem to be stuck on the last point, I tried moving the output to a table in body of page with no joy as yet? Outputs a syntax error on 1st line of table below [advisor]


<tr>
      <td><?php echo "Advisor: ".$yourArray[$j][0].; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo "Count: ".$yourArray[$j][1].; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo "Percentage: ".(round(($yourArray[$j][1]/$totalValue),2)*100).; ?></td>
</tr>

Comment: I don't thinks its a problem with your code, more me just copying it into the table, yoir code outputs fine before I do this..

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in C:\wamp\www\mi_new2.php on line 85 where line 85 is <td><?php echo "Advisor: ".$yourArray[$j][0].; ?></td>

Comment: Drop the trailing "." on the line. The full stop in PHP is used to join strings. Use: *<?php echo "Advisor: ".$yourArray[$j][0]; ?>* instead.

Comment: Hi there, sorry about this its now throws; Notice: Undefined offset: 18 in C:\wamp\www\mi_new2.php on line 85,86,87 with those lines being my table with output code;

 <?php do { ?>
 
<tr>    
      <td><?php echo "Advisor: ".$yourArray[$j][0]; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo "Count: ".$yourArray[$j][1]; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo "Percentage: ".(round(($yourArray[$j][1]/$totalValue),2)*100); ?></td>
</tr>
 
    <?php } while ($row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1)); ?>
</table>

Comment: An Undefined Offset means that the array doesn't exist at that point. My guess is that you are incrementing the $j counter once too many during initialization. Otherwise, you should also look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php to sift through elements in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Query

```
SELECT tblcontacts.ContactFullName AS Advisor, 
COUNT( tblcases.CaseID ) AS Cases,
(COUNT( tblcases.CaseID )*100)/(SELECT COUNT( A.CaseID ) FROM tblcases AS A) as Percentage
FROM tblcases
INNER JOIN tblcontacts ON tblcontacts.ContactID = tblcases.ContactAssignedTo
GROUP BY tblcontacts.ContactFullName
```

Consider the database architecture and data.

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tblcases` (
  `CaseID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ContactAssignedTo` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CaseID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=21 ;

INSERT INTO `tblcases` (`CaseID`, `ContactAssignedTo`) VALUES
(1, 1),(2, 1),(3, 1),(4, 1),(5, 2),(6, 2),(7, 3),(8, 3),(9, 3),(10, 3),(11, 4),(12, 4),(13, 5),(14, 5),(15, 5),(16, 6),(17, 7),(18, 7),(19, 8),(20, 8);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tblcontacts` (
  `ContactID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ContactFullName` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ContactID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;

INSERT INTO `tblcontacts` (`ContactID`, `ContactFullName`) VALUES (1, 'amit 1'),(2, 'amit 2'),(3, 'amit 3'),(4, 'amit 4'),(5, 'amit 5'),(6, 'amit 6');

the result will be like this, which is correct for above data in database.

Advisor     Cases       Percentage

amit 1      4               20.0000

amit 2      2               10.0000

amit 3      4               20.0000

amit 4      2               10.0000

amit 5      3               15.0000

amit 6      1               5.0000

Comment: What if tblcases has records that are not linked to the records returned in the outer query?

Comment: This query is working correct also for the condition mentioned by you.

Comment: No, the "(SELECT COUNT( A.CaseID ) FROM tblcases AS A)" will count ALL records in the tblcases table, not just the ones linked to advisors. Records in tblcases that don't have an advisor in tblContacts will still be returned.